# Was there ever serious speculation that some terrestrial deep sea life might be of alien origin?

Tags: astrobiology

According to [this usually fairly well-researched youtube channel](https://youtu.be/nvYCUSvW7LA?t=36),

> There are also some truly strange critters in the deep sea and some so strange it's been speculated they were alien, and not always as a joke or by a crackpot.

Was there ever serious speculation that some terrestrial deep sea life might be of alien origin?

Comment: I don't see a question here related to Space Exploration.

Comment: While deep sea life appears odd to us due to the enviroment they exist in (we'd look goofy to them to!), nothing in the biochemistry, especially the role of DNA suggests non common descent https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_descent

Comment: From your question it's clear that there has been some speculation that these critters were alien. But there has been no serious speculation that I am aware of in scientific circles. These creatures live in very different conditions from us and are well adapted to their environment (as would be expected) that is why they appear "alien". As to their original origin and ours, it is possible that the biogenesis was extraterrestrial but there is no way to tell.

Comment: If I wanted to ask about this I'd ask either in Astronomy SE or Biology SE. But the question needs to be refined. While I can understand what you mean by "Was there ever serious speculation..." it's easy for answers to argue in an opinion-based way how serious some speculation is or isn't. If the site has a `reference-request` tag use it, and explain that you are asking for help locating scholarly works that propose or at least address this. Questions get quickly closed if some users feel they might attract opinion-based answers. *Good luck* with your interesting question!

Comment: If E.T. is out there, they _might_ have weird morphology (or maybe not—parallel evolution happens) but, they probably would be profoundly different at the molecular level. There's just too many bazillion ways that organic molecules can be put together. Their flesh and their food could be toxic to everything living on Earth and vice versa.

Comment: There is certainly a field of research on whether CIVILIZATIONS have existed on Earth or other planets before humans. I don't have my references handy, but as speculative as it is, it's serious science, and made difficult by the continuous reshaping of the surface through weathering, continental drift, etc. Nothing definite has been found yet, and as far as I've seen this line of research does not extend to sea critters.